# transparent Actionbar with AppCompat-v7 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

Is there a way to make the ActionBar transparent in Material Design via Appcompat-v7 21? This is not working unfortunately.

```
  <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Also not the old:

```
  <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ACTION BAR STYLES -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i think you should see 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
this one
it will tell you how to change action bar color.
tick my answer if you got your answer thanks. vote up you got your answer thanks.

Comment: Fix: It doesn't work if you have an icon in the actionbar. Move the windowActionBarOverlay styles to AppTheme and it will work for all cases.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard you just saved me an hour or two

Comment: what is `actionbar_background` please help?

Answer (score 24):

Actually, it's quite easy and simple.

1. Just ensure that you use `RelativeLayout` to lay `Toolbar` and the body.
2. Put the `Toolbar` in the last.
3. Put transparent color for `android:background` attribute of the `Toolbar`

This is an example of a working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_editor"
        android:name="ichsan.myapp.HelloFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_editor" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#10000000"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it answers the question.

Comment: Nice.  Was working on this for a while before finding your post.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a clean solution on how to swap between an overlaid Toolbar and a top-anchored Toolbar depending on which Fragment is showing within the Activity?

Comment: although this does work, but the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` must be removed. And since it removed the original collapsed toolbar will remain on screen.

Comment: could you please tell how to implement the above layout in an Activity (not FragmentActivity) with "fragment_editor" in **tools:layout="@layout/fragment_editor"** as a recyleview?

Answer (score 1):

**Step:**

**1.** put below style into **v21\styles.xml**

```
<style name="TransperantToolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**2.** Your toolbar xml code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:theme="@style/TransperantToolbar"/>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above did the trick for me (or at least not by themselves)
using appcompat v7 23 and a CoordinatorLayout, which is most likely the culprit. If you are going that route, then you probably have a main activity layout that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.farmdog.farmdog.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
                 app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">-->
     ...
```

Notice the two layout anchor lines above - those did it for me.