# Support library v21 breaks action bar theme

Tags: android

I updated my application with the latest support library and it breaks my theme. It doesn't show menu icons and doesn't applyu changes for translucent action bar.

Did you faced with that?

Answer (score 0):

I faced and solved the translucend actionbar - [transparent Actionbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452431/transparent-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7-21)

The menu-items worked for me since the beginning