# How to make Toolbar transparent?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

**It is self Q&A post**
I have transparent ActionBar which overlays layout. After migration to the latest support library I have been forced to get rid off the ActionBar in favor of the Toolbar. The old ways to make it transparent and overlay that layout doesn't work anymore.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All you need to is to define theme which hide action bar, define action bar style with transparent background and set this style to the toolbar widget. Please note that toolbar should be drawen as last view (over all view tree)

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

Comment: If you use Toolbar, just consider it as a normal View.Now you can do whatever you want: set toolbar background transparent, hide or show it... Just applying style windowActionBarOverlay = true doesnt' work.

Comment: No point defining "Theme.Custom". Nothing use it. I'm afraid it's not a real working Q.A.

Comment: Although it does but there is some problem with it as it does not work when parent is AppBarLayout

Comment: @HuyDuongTu could you please a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192376/how-to-make-the-toolbar-faded-to-blend-in-with-the-layout-underneath#

Answer (score 50):

Create your **toolbar.xml file** with background of AppBarLayout is **@null**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/general_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and here is result:

[image]

Comment: or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: you don't need `AppBarLayout`, just `android:background="@null"` for your `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 41):

Checking Google's example Source Code I found out how to make the toolbar completely transparent. It was simpler than I thought. We just have to create a simple Shape drawable like this.

The name of the drawable is `toolbar_bg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

And then in the fragment or activity.. Add the toolbar like this.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And here we will have a fully transparent toolbar.

[image]

Don't add the `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >` if you do, this won't work.

**Note:** If you need the AppBarLayout, set the elevation to 0 so it doesn't draw its shadow.

Comment: awesome, did you find this caveat in AOSP?

Comment: What's the reason to use a gradient if both colors are the same? Why not simply set the background to transparent?

Comment: @Henry good question. I tried with a solid transparent and didn't work, but you are free to give it a try, maybe now it works.

Comment: @Heny try also this. I have my code like this now.  Set on your theme ..android:colorPrimary>@color/transparent  and ..name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>

Comment: It will hide a whole toolbar (emulator of Android 5.0), but at least it works.

Comment: shape? why just not add @null?

Comment: @CoolMind don't forget to set `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>` in your styles

Comment: Can anyone please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192376/how-to-make-the-toolbar-faded-to-blend-in-with-the-layout-underneath#

Answer (score 22):

The Toolbar works like a View, so the answer it's very simple.

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: This is not very good approach cause loaded mutable bitmap is shared. It's better to use `setBackgroundColor`

Comment: Yes, he can use your way too. It's almost the same.

Comment: How to do this in xml?

Comment: ```android:alpha="0"```

Comment: alpha ,hides `toolbar content` for me

Comment: It will hide all the views of toolbar viewgroup .

Comment: Can anyone help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192376/how-to-make-the-toolbar-faded-to-blend-in-with-the-layout-underneath#

Answer (score 18):

Only this worked for me (AndroidX support library):

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:translationZ="0.1dp"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This code removes background in all necessary views and also removes shadow from AppBarLayout (which was a problem)

Answer was found here: [remove shadow below AppBarLayout widget android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133836/remove-shadow-below-appbarlayout-widget-android/50775140#50775140)

Comment: android:translationZ="0.1dp" is not needed!

Answer (score 14):

Add the following line in style.xml

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppTheme">
</style>
```

Now add the following line in style-v21,

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and set the theme as
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

It will make the status bar transparent.

Answer (score 10):

Just add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`  like below in your appbar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use the following xml code:

Code for the layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/def_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbarTransparent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

And add the following code in the **colors.xml**:

```
<color name="toolbarTransparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
```

This will give you the desired output.

Comment: No, it does not make the Toolbar transparent.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky:  Let me know what have you tried. I can try to help you for sorting out your problem.

Comment: I have a Toolbar inside of AppBarLayout  inside a CoordinatorLayout (all inside a DrawerLayout).  I tried to apply the transparent background to AppBarLayout and Toolbar, but it doesn't become transparent.

Comment: it made toolbar color `white` not `transparent`

Answer (score 5):

I implemented translucent Toolbar by creating two `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` themes and setting `colorPrimary` attribute to transparent color.

1) Create one theme for opaque Toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Toolbar background color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff212cff</item>

</style>
```

Second theme for transparent/overlay Toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Overlay" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

2) In your activity layout, put Toolbar behind content so it can be displayed in front of it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:name="com.test.CustomFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3)
Apply the transparent theme to your acivity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.TransparentActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.test.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Overlay" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.test.HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: primary color has to opaque

Comment: Thank you! `RelativeLayout` instead of `CoordinatorLayout` and `Toolbar` behind a view were especially useful. Now I even can draw a picture behind a StatusBar.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you need to take a look at this post [transparent Actionbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452431/transparent-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7-21/27705929#27705929)

Points that the post suggest are

1. Just ensure that you use RelativeLayout to lay Toolbar and the body.
2. Put the Toolbar in the last.
3. Put transparent color for android:background attribute of the Toolbar

This should solve the problem without too much hassle.

Comment: Why use Actionbar when we have Toolbar??

Comment: The referred post belongs to someone else who initially had problem with ActionBar :)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to put a Toolbar transparent is to define a opacity in **@colors** section, define a TransparentTheme in **@styles** section and then put these defines in your toolbar.

**@colors.xml**

```
<color name="actionbar_opacity">#33000000</color>
```

**@styles.xml**

```
<style name="TransparentToolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**@activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_opacity"
        app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

That's the result:

[Screenshot transparent toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJQXw.png)

Comment: Nice and clean way to answer. Keep it in that way :)

Comment: that's grey, not transparent.

Answer (score 2):

I know am late for the party. I've created a simple class to manage the `Toolbar` transparency.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;



public class TransparentToolbarManager {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ColorDrawable colorDrawable;
    public static final int MAX_ALPHA = 255, MIN_ALPHA = 0;

    public TransparentToolbarManager(Toolbar mToolbar) {
        this.mToolbar = mToolbar;
        this.colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(mToolbar.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    public TransparentToolbarManager(Toolbar mToolbar, ColorDrawable colorDrawable) {
        this.mToolbar = mToolbar;
        this.colorDrawable = colorDrawable;
    }

    //Fading toolbar
    public void manageFadingToolbar(int scrollDistance) {
        if (mToolbar != null && colorDrawable != null) {
            //FadeinAndOut according to the horizontal scrollValue
            if (scrollDistance <= MAX_ALPHA && scrollDistance >= MIN_ALPHA) {
                setToolbarAlpha(scrollDistance);
            } else if (scrollDistance > MAX_ALPHA) {
                setToolbarAlpha(MAX_ALPHA);
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void setToolbarAlpha(int i) {
        colorDrawable.setAlpha(i);
        if (CommonHelper.isSupport(16)) {
            mToolbar.setBackground(colorDrawable);
        } else {
            mToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
    }


}
```

and the CommonHelper.isSupport()

```
public static boolean isSupport(int apiLevel) {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= apiLevel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Add  android:background="#10000000" in your AppBarLayout tag It works

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672153/2914140 helped me.

I made this layout for an activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent" <- Add transparent color in AppBarLayout.
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        <- Remove app:layout_behavior=...
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If this doesn't work, in `onCreate()` of the activity write (where toolbar is @+id/toolbar):

```
toolbar.background.alpha = 0
```

If you want to set a semi-transparent color (like #30ff00ff), then set `toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color)`. Or even set a background color of `AppBarLayout`.

In my case styles of `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` didn't play role.

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"
                    >
                        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

for **Support Toolbar v7** `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`:

**code**

```
toolbar.setBackground(null);
// or
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
```

**xml** (`android:background="@null"` or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

if Title is invisible, set `textColor`

Comment: How to make the AppBarLayout Background fully transparent... I meanwhile scrolling all the view scrolling bottom of the AppBarLayout should be visible...
As it is in Gmail App https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956542/how-i-implement-new-material-gmail-toolbar-without-nested-scrollview

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to `styles.xml` file

```
<style name="LayoutPageTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="TransparentActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Don't forget to write: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score -6):

Go to `res` package and open `color.xml`.
Set color primary to `#00000000`.

Comment: Please add an code example or more explanation to make your answer clearer