# Android transparent overlay toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I created a `ToolBar` which I set as my `ActionBar` and I have it transparent, my question is I want it to overlay the rest of the content, right now it is acting like a normal `ActionBar` where my `LinearLayout` "stops" below it. How do I make my `ToolBar` overlay my layout and have that layout fill the whole screen?

The style for the original `ActionBar` is just:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

My `ToolBar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

and my `ToolBar` declaration:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but after searching I couldn't find the solution I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is my full XML Main Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="rsay.android.scrollbanner.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are on right track. Simplest way you can do it is using `FrameLayout` where the content `ViewGroup` will `match_parent` while the `Toolbar` is on top of this `ViewGroup`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!-- This can be any child. For sample purposes I assume this layout contains fragments -->
    <LinearLayout  
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So this is closer than what I had, I have a `DrawerLayout` as my second child instead of a `LinearLayout` and the navigation drawer is there when I swipe from the left, but the `ToolBar` is not visible, I'm assuming it's behind the other Layout, is there an attribute I need to specify to bring it to the front?

Comment: Views from xml are ordered with the last element displayed at the highest elevation. If you moved the <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/> element after the LinearLayout, it will be displayed on top. I've edited Nikola's response to reflect this.

Comment: Confirmed. Moving the toolbar to be the last element has put it on the top of the main content. My root layout is RelativeLayout.

Comment: Worked in case of `Toolbar` above `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 11):

After some exercise i make it happen. Hope it helps others. here, i set no **elevation** for **appbarlayout**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradiant"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.AddMembersActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_add_member" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Genius you are!

Answer (score 3):

You should set the transparency on the `AppBarLayout` instead of the `Toolbar` and remove the `app:layout_behavior` if you want it to overlay the content.

Comment: Thanks! Removing `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from activity layout and setting `android:background="@color/transparent"` in `AppBarLayout` resolved the problem.

Comment: Also add `toolbar.background.alpha = 0` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

In xml, the ordering of the layouts determine the "depth". By moving the toolbar below the other elements, it will overlay them.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="rsay.android.scrollbanner.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start" />    

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Works as intended but clicks on the underlying fragment don't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.SemiTransp" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/gray_to_transp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SemiTranspActionBar" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.SemiTransp</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SemiTranspActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1):

`CollapsingToolbar` introduced in support library 22.2.0 (May 2015), offers overlay effect by default:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoordinatorLayout as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.epbit.itattooz.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Where frameLayout is for used fragments.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you, Ryan.

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: He clearly stated that he want's the content behind the `Toolbar`. Changing alpha will not make the content go behind the `Toolbar`. If he just changes the alpha, the `Rect` of the drawer will go black/white (depending on the theme) but content will be still below.

Comment: You're right! Maybe he can edit his XML and organize the elements. But, after do that, I think he can use the line that I posted to make his Toolbar overlay the layout.

Comment: He already has Toolbar background set to @android:color/transparent.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that line. He must edit his XML, organize the elements and it's done.

Comment: TBH, I have tried ALL of the SoF solutions for a transparent bar. In my case, it's DrawerLayout > CoordinatorLayout > AppBarLayout > Toolbar. The ONLY way I've been able to get it transparent was to use code, this worked (setAlpha) finally. I also have setBackgroundColor() on the AppBarLayout object to transparent. Still trying to get rid of the elevation... this is a nightmare frankly. Using appcompat-v7:25.3.1 and testing on API 26... thanks Marco.