# Is it possible to overlay custom action bar in android??I have tried everything but I could make it work only with default action bar

Tags: android

This is what I have done.I cannot apply CustomActionBar theme to NoActionBar activity but I need that for custom toolbar.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>

</style>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="Toolbar_Theme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>


</style>
<style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<color name="custom_color">#8C000000</color>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
</style>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `Toolbar` or regular `ActionBar`?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532167/android-transparent-overlay-toolbar

Comment: I am using toolbar and yes that is the problem.