# Android transparent toolbar over an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to have a [transparent toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent),

such that it will be shown ***on top of*** an `ImageView` which is set as follow:

```
<ImageView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    />
```

Illustration (blue area is an `ImageView`):

[image]

so, it is transparent, but it pushes the `ImageView` down, instead of being on top of it.

I also tried using [`android:elevation`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use frame layout

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    // Your imageview

  <ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     //your toolbar


 </FrameLayout>
```

This should help

Answer (score 4):

Toolbar is just ViewGroup. So consider making layout like Relative layout.
In Relative layout, u have such order : the lower position in layout code, then this view would be considered as highest layer of layout. So put your views in correct order and you will achieve desired result. Worked for me many times before.