# How to set background transparent on toolbar in android

Tags: android, background, transparent, android-toolbar

I want to set background of toolbar transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_org"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my toolbar layout  background is not being transparent

just show in white color

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_org);
 toolbar.getbackgroud().setAlpha(0);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Its not working.  Can you please tell me how to make it transparent.

Comment: You need to do that using Themes/Styles of your app.

Comment: @Skynet sir what to change in style  please explain

Comment: When i add this code `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. My toolbar's background is being transparent.

Comment: @Cbibejs but Mine Showing in white ...i want to show image below the toolbar

Comment: Your mountain image have top padding or is it below toolbar?If you change your main layout 's background to mountain image than it should be visible at behind of toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This is the theme I have used in my project to make the appCompact ActionBar  as transparent, modify it according to your needs:

```
<style name="adhoctheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/adhocblack</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/adhocblack</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="adhocblack" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#0D000000</item>
        <item name="background">@color/appcompact_transparent_actionbar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo_header_2</item>
    </style>
```

Where `appcompact_transparent_actionbar_bg = #0D000000`

#### Important:

Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/TextSwitcher/res/values-v14/styles.html) to check how different values folders contain specific style files to render on various API's

Comment: let me check this Thanks

Comment: [imagescreen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/htfmyzj3vijkxhj/Capture.PNG?dl=0)  this is screen shot .when iused your theme 

i want to show toolbar on image mean image is below to toolbar

Comment: For that you have to add the image to the toolbar, actually your problem is not quite clear. Please provide more examples. What API are you testing on? Please take note of how values folders are used to render different styles for different API's

Comment: The Example Is Google play store  when we click on any app toolbar is showing on the below image banner .....

Comment: [Check this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) and [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) library

Comment: i Used   <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
this item overlaying is not done

Comment: What is the API you are testing on? DId you use AppCompact as the parent theme?

Comment: [Check a similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent)