# Transparent toolbar

Tags: android, background, toolbar, transparent

I have an application with a Toolbar and I want to make the Toolbar transparent.
I have searched and got some answers but they are not working at all!

now I sign up and asking question , how should i make my Toolbar transparent? (I mean no background at all).
my API is 15, android 4.0.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
```

Comment: What in that toolbar layout do you think would make your toolbar transparent? Have you tried simply setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: @Tanis.7x not working , gives me white toolbar!

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a white view behind your toolbar?

Comment: umm sorry did not get what you mean... @Tanis.7x

Comment: If your toolbar is transparent, then anything behind it will be visible. It sounds like you just have a white view behind the toolbar. Please post the rest of your layout (not just the Toolbar).

Comment: no i dont have a white back i have a music concert picture so its not... and hey the second answer below gives me white color too! @Tanis.7x

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the Toolbar in your Java Activity, try using this code to set the Opacity/Alpha value like so:

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Also you could use this theme to set the background to empty

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Toolbar, set the theme with this value

```
app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

Comment: beside when i use the setAplpha i get a force close... why?

Comment: I am guessing it is because you did not initialize the toolBar or you added the toolbar.getBackground()... line of code before initializing the toolbar

Comment: tell me how can i set an action bar color to transparent in theme.xml or style.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

set toolbar hidden: yes maybe it can work.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question asked by OP. If done by this method, the toolbar will be gone. The OP wants the toolbar to be transparent.

Comment: I am voting to close this as this has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent