# remove shadow below AppBarLayout widget android

Tags: android, android-layout

When using `AppBarLayout` widget in design support library, a shadow appears on the bottom of the toolbar. How can I remove that shadow?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Simply use `app:elevation="0dp"` inside "AppBarLayout" to remove the shadow. It has always worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Don't use android:elevation. Use app:elevation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically without getting the warning that setting elevation is only available after L?

Comment: app:elevation="0dp", shade is removed, but now tabs are not clickable .

Comment: Setting it to 0dp is hiding the Toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately no longer a working answer. See Liu Teng answer below with `setOutlineProvider`

Comment: use AppBarLayout.setTargetElevation() to set programatically.

Comment: This has a side-effect of making the buttons unclickable for me

Answer (score 60):

**this problem only occurs when api version >= 21,** try below codes:

```
appBar.setOutlineProvider(null);
```

remember to check api version

---

**EDIT :**

Below is the source code of `setOutlineProvider`.

```
   /**
     * Sets the {@link ViewOutlineProvider} of the view, which generates the Outline that defines
     * the shape of the shadow it casts, and enables outline clipping.
     * <p>
     * The default ViewOutlineProvider, {@link ViewOutlineProvider#BACKGROUND}, queries the Outline
     * from the View's background drawable, via {@link Drawable#getOutline(Outline)}. Changing the
     * outline provider with this method allows this behavior to be overridden.
     * <p>
     * If the ViewOutlineProvider is null, if querying it for an outline returns false,
     * or if the produced Outline is {@link Outline#isEmpty()}, shadows will not be cast.
     * <p>
     * Only outlines that return true from {@link Outline#canClip()} may be used for clipping.
     *
     * @see #setClipToOutline(boolean)
     * @see #getClipToOutline()
     * @see #getOutlineProvider()
     */
    public void setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider provider) {
        mOutlineProvider = provider;
        invalidateOutline();
    }
```

It is said that `If the ViewOutlineProvider is null, if querying it for an outline returns false, or if the produced Outline is {@link Outline#isEmpty()}, shadows will not be cast.`

So, if you want to remove shadow, **you'd better use this method instead of setting `app:elevation`.** It seems like that changing the elevation to remove shadow is a kind of side effect. And changing the elevation may cause some other problems in some cases.

Comment: API is available only from version 21.

Comment: What to do with API < 21?

Comment: this problems only occurs when api >= 21

Answer (score 14):

For all those who do not want to use `bringToFront()` and `elevation="0dp"` makes the toolbar disappear:

`app:elevation="0dp"` combinded with `android:translationZ="0.1dp"` worked for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:translationZ="0.1dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

With latest appcompat versions, the trick setting `app:elevation="0.1dp"` in xml doesn't work any more.

So far I have found two solutions.

1. Instead of setting `app:elevation`, try to use a stateListAnimator. For example, in code:

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
       stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(appBarLayout, "elevation", 0.1f));
       appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
   }
   ```
2. An easier way is you still set `app:elevation="0dp"` in xml as normal, but in code:

   ```
   appBarLayout.bringToFront();
   ```

Credit goes to these two discussions:

[ToolBar disappears when setting elevation for AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969292/toolbar-disappears-when-setting-elevation-for-appbarlayout)

[when set app:elevation="0dp" then hamburgermenu not showing to toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931245/when-set-appelevation-0dp-then-hamburgermenu-not-showing-to-toolbar)

Answer (score 8):

Use `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`. No side effect.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    >
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Neither app:elevation="0dp", android:elevation="0dp" nor android:outlineProvider="none" worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `app:elevation="0dp"` but the toolbar desappear, but using `app:elevation="0.1dp"` made the trick.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: 0.1dp is also not working, It is also hiding the Toolbar Menu.

Comment: I've a working app with appcompat v23.0.1 using this tips, what version do you have?

Comment: I am using `v25.0.0`.

Comment: It seems not working anymore with  updated versions :(.

Answer (score 2):

Add app:elevation="0dp" on your AppBarLayout. like this example

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Life saving answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use this : 
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0.0f);

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I came up with `app:elevation="0dp"` to remove the shadow.Perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this on Kotlin minSdkVersion 21 with AppBarLayout & TabLayout so: `app:elevation="0dp"` does indeed help me solve the shadow problem BUT using this solution make it so that I will not be able to press the button on the TabLayout.

so combine `app:elevation="0.1dp"` & `app:elevation="0dp"`i can fix the shadow and still be able to interact with my tab layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `outlineProvider` attribute in case you use the XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
                android:outlineProvider="none" />
```