# set as image as header CollapsingToolbarLayout on Collapse

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to stick image as background of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` when collapsed. I am able to show image in expanded form on `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but when the collapsed image disappears, I want the effect of the following GIF image:

[image]

My structure is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorGreen"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/prof_img_picBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                ndroid:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    style="@style/overscroll_remove"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your issue got resolved? I am also looking for this kind of implementation.

Comment: how did you implement that?

Comment: @DevendraSingh, ok i am writing down my answer, from there you can can use it.

Comment: @VikramSingh No, i thought you have done this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262776/add-icon-with-title-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout-android . actually i post a question here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create your them with this link, [Transparent toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent/38897656#38897656) and set it as theme of your activity

xml code is as follows,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and in activity,

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(itemTitle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `contentScrim` attribute from `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just simply set contentScrim to a transparent color.

E.g.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="@color/ap_transparent" <-- this line
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
```