# Set transparent toolbar while using navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to remove toolbar while we are using navigation drawer?

[image]

I want to make the toolbar transparent like below shown image

[image]

Comment: make your toolbar transparent with no views

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see if you are using the support toolbar or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent/38897656#38897656, it will work for you, as for me also now solution worked.

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#38b3d2"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />