# app:elevation="0dp" hide layout inside toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appbarlayout, appbar

I have take custom layout inside the toolbar and perform action according to it.
but in some case i want make toolbar transparent so when i have set `app:elevation="0dp"` than it will hide my custom layout but still action will performed when click on that area.

I have used following layout inside toolbar.

**Edited**

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frmNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_menu"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_menu"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_notification"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_notification" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_5"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_bage">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/eight"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_8" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </FrameLayout>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frmNotification"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_header" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivElasticSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_15"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

How to overcome this issue because in some scenario we want transparent toolbar but icon inside it should be display.

Here I have attached image how actually look like.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of `app:elevation="someValue"` is wrong, it does not hide the toolbar.The attribute `app:elevation` is used to show how much you want to make the `toolbar` or any other `view` that supports that attribute raised above the surface. Consider the surface as the floor on which the views are placed, now if you want to show some view like `toolbar` raised to other views you use that attribute.
if you want to make it transparent do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505771/7822626).

According to [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html), the elevation for `appbar` should be `4dp`. So you should not set it to `0dp`.

Comment: Thank you very much @dexter for reply you are right.
But when i have used toolbar.setVisibility='invisible' OR transparent theme then My Layout will also hide that's the main problem.

Comment: can you post a image link on what's happening? or your updated code? and sorry for guiding you wrong don't set the visibility to invisible cause you want some actions performed on toolbar. Also I saw your code mentioned elevation to both `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`, don't do it just give elevation to `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: I have update code above and also used below method for transparent
 public void changeAppBarBackgroundTransparent() {
        appBarMain.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
     //        setTheme(R.style.TransparentActionBar);
}

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background="@null"` instead of `app:elevation="0dp"`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null">
```

**EDIT**

You want to remove the shadow of the toolbar. To do that use `app:elevation="0dp"` only for appbar layout. Your code before revision shows you used for both toolbar and appbar. Remove it for toolbar.

**UPDATE**

I tested the code and the following code seemed to do the work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/testbg">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <!-- Rest of the code -->

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Abhi for the reply but still my need is not fulfill.

Comment: You wanted transparent toolbar. Does the above code not solve that issue?

Comment: Hello@Abhi using app:elevation = "0dp" my toolbar will hide that is correct but i want to display the icons which is already added in toolbar see my xml code.(Hide toolbar + show icons)

Comment: Hello @Abhi have you take imageview inside the toolbar (Rest of the code area) ?

Comment: Yes the imageView is within the toolbar. Your code was unaltered; changes were only made in the AppBarLayout and Toolbar.