# How to make toolbar transparent who's parent is Appbarlayout?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appbarlayout, navigation-drawer

I have tried using styles and android:background:"@null" / android:background:"@color/transparent" inside AppBarLayout as well as inside V7 toolbar nothing seems to workout.
Have tried these solutions too :

1.[How to make Toolbar transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    app:itemTextColor="#c92e30">
  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have included this layout

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.g5web.aastha.activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/signin"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/frame_container" />
<!--</LinearLayout>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your AppBarLayout you need to set

> android:background="@null"

or

> android:background="@android:color/transparent"

im testing it right now and it's working for me

The thing is that if you have layouts inside your toolbar like here you probably need to set their backgrounds aswell

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/signin"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have already tried with android:background:"@null" / android:background:"@color/transparent"  which was not working. I even tried setting the same in layouts under the toolbar which is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. any specific attributes need to be applied to Apptheme.PopupOverlay  in styles ? as your solution is also not working.

Comment: @ Shubham Vala  @JoaquinAlvarez I just tried putting Toolbar inside FrameLayout and removing AppBarLayout now it seems to work.