# android : setting status and navigation bar color

Tags: android, background, uinavigationbar, statusbar

For my activity, i am setting a background color for the window as

```
window.decorView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red)
```

Now i want the status and navigation to get a darker shade over this background. How can i get this.
I tried setting the theme as

```
`<style name="Theme.OnArrival.AccessControl" parent="Theme.OnArrival.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

    </style>`
```

but it doesnt seem to be working for navigation bar. Whats the right way to do it

Comment: Have a look at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39151794/3809653)

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically set status bar color use below code:

```
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.statusbar_color));
```

Or set `colorPrimaryDark` in your Theme.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) for more details.

Comment: i just need a shade over the window color. I dont know exact color for status bar / navigation bar