# How I implement new material gmail toolbar without nested scrollview?

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui, toolbar

I want to implement new gmail like toolbar without nested scroll view, which is scroll able, but when scroll down background should be visible.

It will look like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Were you able to implement it? @koushik

Answer (score 3):

It's not a nested scrollview, Its [recyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).
If you want such a search bar, you can make it using [CardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview) and Edittext or use [Material searchba](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar)r library. You can place it locked at that position by using frameLayout or CoordinatorLayout.

Here is a sample Screen I made!.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#dadada"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Search..."
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: How to implement Searching in this?

Comment: Make your search feature a new activity, link to it... That is what Gmail did. With nice animations of course.

Answer (score 2):

You just need create custom one in your Activity layout like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And change style of your activity to "NoActionBar". For me it help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is trying to implement this with a `RecyclerView` , just use item view types with different layouts.
BaseAdapter that holds the main data:

```
public class BaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder> 

 @Override
    @NonNull
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
// this is the main adapter so by default
// it should display the main content.
// Notice the layout being inflated here
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_song_list, null);
        return createViewHolder(v);

    }
// BaseViewHolder is the ViewHolder of this adapter
    protected BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(View view) {
        return new BaseViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BaseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // Do something here
    }
```

Now create an abstract adapter that extends the previous adapter:

```
public abstract class BaseHeaderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected static final int ITEM_HEADER = 0;
    protected static final int ITEM_LIST = 1;

   @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == ITEM_HEADER) {
// Notice the layout being inflated here
// This is a different layout
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_tab_header, parent, false);
            return createViewHolder(view);
        }
// This will return the default layout from the extended adapter
        return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }
// BaseAdapter and BaseViewHolder are extended
    @Override
    protected BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(View view) {
// Notice: BaseHeaderAdapter is the current adapter
// BaseViewHolder is the extended holder
        return new BaseHeaderAdapter.BaseViewHolder(view);
    }

 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int superItemCount = super.getItemCount();
        return superItemCount == 0 ? 0 : superItemCount + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? ITEM_HEADER : ITEM_LIST;
    }
// This adapter's ViewHolder
public class BaseHeaderViewHolder extends BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder {
...
}

}
```

Now the adapter that displays everything:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseHeaderAdapter
.....
@Override
    protected BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(View view) {
        return new MyAdapter.BaseViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == ITEM_HEADER) {
// do some stuff
            holder.mHeaderTitle.setText("Header");
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position - 1);
        }
    }
// The ViewHolder extends the BaseHeaderAdapter.BaseHeaderViewHolder
```

[image: Final result 2][image: Final result 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with an `AppBarLayout` and a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`. First, setup the layout in this way:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior=".view.SearchBarBehaviour">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            .../>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <!-- the searchbar with a layout_margin and transparent background etc -->
        <include layout="@layout/searchbar" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note the custom behavior set to the SwipeRefreshLayout. It looks like that:

```
class SearchBarBehaviour(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>(context, attrs) {

    private var previousY: Float = 0f

    override fun layoutDependsOn(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout, 
        child: View, dependency: View
    ): Boolean = dependency is AppBarLayout

    override fun onDependentViewChanged(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout, 
        child: View, 
        dependency: View
    ): Boolean {
        val currentY = dependency.y
        // When the AppBarLayout scrolls, scroll the RecyclerView for the same distance
        (child as SwipeRefreshLayout)
            .getChildAt(0)
            .scrollBy(0, (previousY - currentY).toInt())

        previousY = currentY
        return false
    }
}
```

This obviously also works without a `SwipeRefreshLayout` if you attach the behavior directly to a `RecyclerView`/`NestedScrollView`/... and adjust the line in the custom behaviour to scroll the child itself.

This solves the `RecyclerView` resizing issue of the default `ScrollingViewBehavior` which causes the `RecyclerView` to pop up its items when scrolling down.