# Collapsing View (not AppBarLayout) on scroll with CoordinatorLayout like in new GMail Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I would like to implement panel like in new GMail (look at [How I implement new material gmail toolbar without nested scrollview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956542/how-i-implement-new-material-gmail-toolbar-without-nested-scrollview)).

In above link there is recipe how to achieve view (`CardView`) but I am interested in how to implement collapsing/expanding (hide/show) effect like in `AppBarLayout` but without `AppBarLayout`.
Can you give me a some advice? Should I add `Behaviour` to my `CardView`?

[effect I want to achieve -> gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdWa.gif)

Comment: Where is answer how to implement collapsing effect? Because I cannot see it. I don't want to have first item  as header. I'd like to scroll down in the middle of list and see toolbar is scrolling down like `AppBarLayout`. Your answer is not useful at all.

Comment: Look at gif I've added.

Comment: The closest to that behavior I can think of is using a NestedScrollView that holds both layouts. Otherwise, animating the toolbar onScrollListener is a better idea.