# Design transparent glass type bar with gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient

I am trying to design a transparent glass type bar like this -

[image]

I am poor in designing. How can I achieve it. Is there any property?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that you use RelativeLayout to lay Toolbar and the body.
Put the Toolbar in the last.
Put transparent color for android:background attribute of the Toolbar
This is an example of a working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_editor"
        android:name="ichsan.myapp.HelloFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_editor" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#10000000"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Source : [transparent Actionbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452431/transparent-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7-21#answer-27705929)

Answer (score 0):

The glass style background is a bit more complex than just simple transparency. You might wanna use [intrinsic blur](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/02/create-blur-bitmap-using-renderscript.html). So the way to do this would be take a simple white image, perform intrinsic blur -> set the blurred output bitmap as the background for your `toolbar`. Now set alpha to somewhere around `0.6f` and you will have something similar. It won't exactly be exactly like the image you provided, but might be the easiest way to get a similar effect.